# Long running HTTP request and threads synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

I need to code a web service that solves a complex problem by the use of a heuristic algorithm. The algorithm will run as long as the amount of time specified in the POST request has lapsed (i.e. passing timeAllowance=60 will make sure that the heuristic algorithm stops after 60 seconds and returns the best solution found).

The heuristic algorithm has to run on several threads to take advantage of all the server cores. During the execution of the algorithm, these methods have to "communicate" between each other. Each thread will run the heuristic algorithm and after certain amount of time, the threads will communicate the solutions they found and, if the allowed time has not expired, a new cycle is run with a different initial population. Summarizing:

1. Generate initial populations (pretty much randomly)
2. Launch heuristic algorithms threads, each one taking a population as input
3. After a certain amount of time, terminate the threads and communicate to a "controller entity" the new populations found by the threads
4. Do some logical reasoning and generate the new populations based on the result of the threads launched at point 2
5. If the allowed time has not expired, go back to point 2 with the new populations. Otherwise quit

My question is: how would you structure the code using Spring MVC?

Just as a test, I tried to launch 10 threads in a service method and to call that method from a controller (autowiring the service). Everything the threads are doing is to sleep for 60 seconds. I was expecting the HTTP request to wait for all the threads to terminate (i.e. about 60 seconds), but it actually responds straight away.

Any help very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want thread, you want a thread pool ([`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)). Submit some number of `Callable<HeuristicResult>` to your pool and wait on returned [`Future<HeuristicResult>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). Once all futures are done, do your point 4. and go back to 2. (but reusing the thread pool).

At the end shutdown the pool or reuse it for all requests (more scalable).

> I tried to launch 10 threads [...] I was expecting the HTTP request to wait for all the threads to terminate [...], but it actually responds straight away.

Starting a thread is non-blocking and from that moment thread works asynchronously. You can call `join()` on created thread to wait for its termination. But a thread pool and `Future.get()` is much more modern and flexible.

Comment: exactly this - from the question it sounds like the background threads are started and never joined

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code I would guess that reason this returned straight away is that you started the task in a background thread not the thread servicing the request.

If I were writing this service I would probably not wait for 60 seconds before returning the response. I would start the task in the background (using a service) and return a status page immediately. On this page you could use ajax to poll the server for the status of the task and use javascript to render a progress bar in the browser.

Therefore you would need a controller method to start the process and one to allow the browser to obtain the status. Since you just need the time since it started to derive the progress I would most likely just put the start time and total allowed time in the session. Then you need a controller method to calculate the percentage of time elapsed and return that to the browser.